XML Reading with several data after "Name"
Here is the xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CFaveDefn-v000 Description="Favourite definitions, Default group" Created="18-Apr-2024 14:49">
    <Defn>
        <Display m_display.contrast.bEnabled="true" m_display.contrast.nLow="-138" m_display.contrast.nHigh="-80" m_display.scale.bEnabled="true" m_display.scale.nLow="-151" m_display.scale.nHigh="-42" m_display.bEnabled="true" m_display.bSmallIcon="true" m_display.n64FreqLow="2801644" m_display.nBandwidth="63913" />
        <Radio m_radio.bEnabled="false" m_radio.n64FreqLow="2801644" m_radio.nBandwidth="63913" />
        <Flags m_flags.bDefault="false" />
        <Name m_name.strGroup="-- UNKNOWN" m_name.strFolder="MIL-STD 188-141 - ALE" m_name.strTitle="2.835,000 ALE LSB unk-tx TIS:K01 TO:K13 +110" />
        <RX m_rx.nActive="0" m_rx.anEnabled="1" m_rx.astrDemod_count="1" m_rx.astrDemod_value_0="&lt;CDSPDemodRX-v000>&lt;Audio m_audio.bASIO=&quot;false&quot; m_audio.bEnable=&quot;true&quot; m_audio.nLevel=&quot;100&quot; m_audio.nDevice=&quot;-1&quot; m_audio.nChannels=&quot;0&quot; m_audio.szDevice=&quot;Default&quot;/>&lt;Freq m_freq.n64RX=&quot;2835000&quot; m_freq.n64TX=&quot;10000000&quot; m_freq.n64RXOffset=&quot;0&quot;/>&lt;Mode m_mode.nMode=&quot;0&quot;/>&lt;Main m_main.nID=&quot;0&quot; m_main.bTX=&quot;false&quot; m_main.bLock_0=&quot;false&quot;/>&lt;Filter m_filter.nLow=&quot;100&quot; m_filter.nHigh=&quot;2700&quot; m_filter.nTaps=&quot;257&quot; m_filter.nWindowing=&quot;3&quot;/>&lt;AGC m_agc.nAGC=&quot;1&quot; m_agc.levels_0.nDecay=&quot;0&quot; m_agc.levels_0.nGain=&quot;40&quot; m_agc.levels_0.nHang=&quot;0&quot; m_agc.levels_0.nKnee=&quot;0&quot; m_agc.levels_0.nSlope=&quot;0&quot; m_agc.levels_1.nDecay=&quot;250&quot; m_agc.levels_1.nGain=&quot;0&quot; m_agc.levels_1.nHang=&quot;100&quot; m_agc.levels_1.nKnee=&quot;-130&quot; m_agc.levels_1.nSlope=&quot;6&quot; m_agc.levels_2.nDecay=&quot;500&quot; m_agc.levels_2.nGain=&quot;0&quot; m_agc.levels_2.nHang=&quot;250&quot; m_agc.levels_2.nKnee=&quot;-130&quot; m_agc.levels_2.nSlope=&quot;6&quot; m_agc.levels_3.nDecay=&quot;1000&quot; m_agc.levels_3.nGain=&quot;0&quot; m_agc.levels_3.nHang=&quot;500&quot; m_agc.levels_3.nKnee=&quot;-130&quot; m_agc.levels_3.nSlope=&quot;6&quot;/>&lt;CW m_cw.bEnable=&quot;false&quot; m_cw.nLevel=&quot;48&quot;/>&lt;NB m_nb.bEnable=&quot;false&quot; m_nb.nThreshold=&quot;50&quot; m_nb.nWidth=&quot;50&quot;/>&lt;NR m_nr.bEnable=&quot;false&quot; m_nr.nMethod=&quot;0&quot; m_nr.nLMSThreshold=&quot;50&quot; m_nr.nRRNoise1=&quot;5&quot; m_nr.nLMSWidth=&quot;50&quot; m_nr.nLMSLevel=&quot;10&quot; m_nr.nSpectralReduction_0=&quot;3&quot; m_nr.nSpectralThreshold_0=&quot;10&quot; m_nr.nSpectralRescale_0=&quot;2&quot; m_nr.cleanup.nBins=&quot;0&quot; m_nr.cleanup.nMultiply=&quot;0&quot; m_nr.cleanup.nSquelch=&quot;0&quot; m_nr.cleanup.nLevel=&quot;0&quot; m_nr.cleanup.nWidth=&quot;0&quot; m_nr.cleanup.bPCS=&quot;0&quot; m_nr.cleanup.bSquelch=&quot;0&quot;/>&lt;Notch m_notch.bEnable=&quot;false&quot; m_notch.nLevel=&quot;50&quot;/>&lt;Squelch m_squelch.fm.hWnd=&quot;69082&quot; m_squelch.fm.nMsg=&quot;50078&quot; m_squelch.fm.bAuto=&quot;false&quot; m_squelch.fm.bCTCSS=&quot;false&quot; m_squelch.fm.bEnable=&quot;false&quot; m_squelch.fm.nCTCSSTone=&quot;67000&quot; m_squelch.fm.nCTCSSLevel=&quot;5&quot; m_squelch.fm.nLevel=&quot;2&quot; m_squelch.vad.bEnable=&quot;false&quot; m_squelch.vad.nCache=&quot;25&quot; m_squelch.vad.nLevel=&quot;25&quot; m_squelch.vad.nHang=&quot;250&quot;/>&lt;/CDSPDemodRX-v000>" />
        <TX m_tx.strMod="" />
    </Defn>
</CFaveDefn-v000>

I have a xml document with several data under the name "RX".
So far I can only read the first name in "RX" that is "m_rx.nActive" which is value "0".
I need to read 2 data:

Freq m_freq.n64RX="2835000" (I need the 2835000 value)
Mode m_mode.nMode="0" (I need the "0" in "0&quot")

Dim xmlToTxt As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(filename)
        '<Name m_name.strGroup="-- UNKNOWN" m_name.strFolder="MIL-STD 188-141 - ALE" m_name.strTitle="4.498,000 ALE TWS:VP TO:RP unk-tx" />

Do While xmlToTxt.Read()
    If xmlToTxt.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element AndAlso xmlToTxt.Name = "RX" Then
        MsgBox(xmlToTxt.GetAttribute(0) & "   <>")  'm_rx.nActivate="0" i can read
    End If
Loop


While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
Please edit your original question and provide the following:
(1) Well-formed XML file sample.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.

You can find a variety of posts here that may be helpful.

Please try the following solution based on LINQ to XML API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.
It will work for XML with multiple <RX> elements.
VB.NET
Private Sub Main()
    Const FILENAME As String = "e:\Temp\Raimund.xml"
    Dim xdoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

    For Each elem In xdoc.Descendants("RX")
        Dim m_rx As XAttribute = elem.Attribute("m_rx.astrDemod_value_0")
        Dim rx As XElement = XElement.Parse(m_rx.Value)
        Console.WriteLine("Frequency='{0}', Mode='{1}'", _
            rx.Descendants("Freq").SingleOrDefault().Attribute("m_freq.n64RX").Value, _
            rx.Descendants("Mode").SingleOrDefault().Attribute("m_mode.nMode").Value)
    Next
End Sub

Output
Frequency='2835000', Mode='0'
Frequency='2835001', Mode='0'


Try following powershell script (can be converted to VBnet)
using assembly System.Xml.Linq
$filename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($filename)
$defn = $doc.Descendants('Defn') | foreach({[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]$_})

$defs = @{}
foreach($def in $defn[0].Elements())
{
   foreach($attr in $def.Attributes())
   {
      if($attr.Value.StartsWith('<'))
      {
         $element = [System.Xml.Linq.Xelement]::Parse($attr.Value)
         foreach($ele in $element.Elements())
         {
            $defs[$ele.Name.LocalName] = $ele.Value
         }
      }
      else `
      {
         $defs[$attr.Name.LocalName] = $attr.Value
      }
   }
   
}
$defs

Results
Name                           Value
----                           -----
m_display.scale.bEnabled       true
NB
NR
Notch
m_rx.nActive                   0
m_name.strTitle                2.835,000 ALE LSB unk-tx TIS:K01 TO:K13 +110
Main
m_display.bEnabled             true
m_display.contrast.bEnabled    true
m_radio.bEnabled               false
m_display.contrast.nHigh       -80
AGC
m_tx.strMod
m_display.n64FreqLow           2801644
Freq
m_name.strFolder               MIL-STD 188-141 - ALE
m_radio.nBandwidth             63913
m_name.strGroup                -- UNKNOWN
m_display.nBandwidth           63913
m_display.bSmallIcon           true
m_rx.astrDemod_count           1
m_radio.n64FreqLow             2801644
Audio
Filter
m_flags.bDefault               false
m_display.scale.nLow           -151
m_display.contrast.nLow        -138
m_rx.anEnabled                 1
Squelch
CW
Mode
m_display.scale.nHigh          -42


Thank you jdweng. I converted to VB.net and try it. Will let you know. Thank you again.

The procedure is working. I get only the data from "<Name..... If it is not possible to get the data from "<RX ....." i could use the Frequency under "<Name..." that is indicated as "m_name.strTitle="2.835,000...." and would use a standard 'Mode' "0" that is "USB".

I think i got it. I changed: if($attr.Value.StartsWith('<')) in if($attr.Value.StartsWith('<RX')) and see the "Freq m_freq.n64RX="2835000&quot". 2835000 is the Frequency / 1000 = 2835,000.

It works. The only thing is my xml file has about 80 records starting with "<RX". How change the procedure for reading the complete xml file? Thank you.

I read exactly what i need. Frequency and the 'Mode' but only for one Record.

First Record is ending with  and starting with  for next record.

Ho do i confirm your last answer (VB.net) as the right one ? It works perfectly.

You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image).
Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted".

I confirmed you aswer as the right one. Thank you again.

the code gets all the data in the first 'Defn' tag.  If you have more than one 'Defn' than you need a foreach loop to enumerate through all the 'Defn'.  So change From : $defn[0].Elements() To : $defx.Elements() and add : foreach($defx in $defn)
